# Require js with Knockout js - Unable to fetch data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

New to require js and still learning with knockout js. Im implementing require js on an existing project I had going but can't get it to go and fetch my data via ajax. Im currently getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: GDI_Application.fetchdata is not a function` when I try to run this line `GDI_Application.fetchdata();`. I need that function to launch for the whole thing to come alive.

I try debugging the code by putting console.logs at different sections of the function but none of it is coming back. So it's not even trying to launch it. I even tried `incidentViewModel.fetchdata();` in the console but comes back with the same error. Then tried doing `incidentViewModel.fetchdata;` for giggles but I get back `undefined`.

Below is the code I got so far. The problem seems to be on the Main.js file or the GDI_Application file. Been staring at it all morning but not spotting anything obvious.

Looking for any advice at this point. What do you guys think would be the problem?

Main.js file code:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jqueryUI": "../assets/jqueryUI/jquery-ui.min",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap.min",
        "bootstrap_select": "../assets/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-a8ed49e/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min",
        "jquery_timepicker": "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon",
        "jqueryui_timepicker_ext":  "jquery-ui-sliderAccess",
        "moment": "moment",
        "cookie": "js.cookie",
        "knockout-amd-helpers": "knockout-amd-helpers.min",
        "text": "text"
    },
        "shim": {
        bootstrap: {
            deps : [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap'
        },
        bootstrap_select: {
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'bootstrap'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap_Select'
        },      
        jquery_timepicker: {
            deps : [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Jquery_Timepicker'
        },
        jqueryui_timepicker_ext: {
            deps : [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Jqueryui_Timepicker_Ext'
        }   
    }
});

require(["knockout", "GDI_Application", "GDI_Buttons", "GDI_common", "knockout-amd-helpers", "text", "moment"], function (ko, GDI_Application) {
ko.amdTemplateEngine.defaultPath = "../templates";

ko.applyBindings(new GDI_Application());
GDI_Application.fetchdata();
});
```

Here is my GDI_Application.js file:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery", "jqueryUI", "bootstrap", "bootstrap_select","jquery_timepicker", "jqueryui_timepicker_ext", "moment"], function(ko, $) {

ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).modal({
            show: false
        });

        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            $(element).on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
               value(false);
            });
        }
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
           $(element).modal("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal('show');
        } else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
}

incidentViewModel = function IncidentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.showDialog = ko.observable(false);
    self.incidents = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentIncident = ko.observable();

    Incident.BASE_URL = '../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_DEV_Incidents';
    Incident.CREATE_HEADERS = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
    Incident.UPDATE_HEADERS = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","If-Match": "*"};

    self.fetchdata = function() {
    console.log("fetching - Attempting to execute code.");
    $.getJSON(Incident.BASE_URL+filterlist+orderlist,
        function(data) {        
            if (data.d.results) {       
                self.incidents(data.d.results.map(function(item) {
                return new Incident(item);
                }));
                $('#loading').hide("slow");
                $('#IncidentTable').show("slow");
                console.log("fetching data completed");
            }else {
                console.log("no results received from server");
                }
        });
    }

    self.saveorupdate = function() {
    console.log("save function executed");
        var id = this.ID,
            url = Incident.BASE_URL + (id ? '(' + encodeURIComponent(id) + ')' : '');
            console.log(url);
        return $.ajax(url, {
            type: id ? "MERGE" : "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON({
                Description: this.Description,
                Incident: this.Incident
            }),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: id ? Incident.UPDATE_HEADERS : Incident.CREATE_HEADERS,
            success: function (data) {
                        incidentViewModel.fetchdata();
                        console.log("Record was sucessfully saved.");

                        }   
        });
    }

    self.ShowSelectedIncident = function(data) {
        self.currentIncident(data);
        self.showDialog(true);
        console.log("The show selected incident has been ran.");    
    }   

    self.clearCurrentIncident = function() {
        self.showDialog(false);
        self.currentIncident(null);
    }

    self.AddNewIncident = function() {
        self.showDialog(true);
        self.currentIncident({ID:"",Description:"",Incident:""});
    }   
}

function Incident(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID;
    self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    self.Composante = ko.observable(data.Composante);
    self.Incident = ko.observable(data.Incident);
    self.ÉtatValue = ko.observable(data.ÉtatValue);
    self.PrioritéValue = ko.observable(data.PrioritéValue);
    self.Duré = ko.observable(data.Duré);
    self.Service = ko.observable(data.Service);
    self.Début_imputabilité = ko.observable(data.Début_imputabilité);
    self.Début_de_interruption = ko.observable(data.Début_de_interruption);
    self.Fin_de_interruption = ko.observable(data.Fin_de_interruption);
    self.Groupe_Support_Prime = ko.observable(data.Groupe_Support_Prime);
    self.ResponsableValue = ko.observable(data.ResponsableValue);
    self.Impact = ko.observable(data.Impact);
    self.Dépanage = ko.observable(data.Dépanage);
    self.Suivi = ko.observable(data.Suivi);
    self.Ressources = ko.observable(data.Ressources); 
}

return incidentViewModel;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code, fetchdata is not a static call. It requires an instance. Change the following code:

```
ko.applyBindings(new GDI_Application());
GDI_Application.fetchdata();
```

to:

```
var app = new GDI_Application();
ko.applyBindings(app);
app.fetchdata();
```

Hope this helps.